# Can i use a button to save data in sharedPreferences and another to retrieve it?

Tags: android, button, save, sharedpreferences

Lets say i have an TextView that i want the user to view and then hit a save button. Then Hit display button and input the text into an editText field.

Here's what Im trying but its not working

To Save info from a TextView...

```
 case R.id.save:


 SharedPreferences firsttunesettings = getSharedPreferences("tune1", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = firsttunesettings.edit();
            editor.putString("rh1", rh1.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
```

then to show the data in an EditText....

```
 case R.id.display:
SharedPreferences firsttunesettings = getSharedPreferences("tune1", 0);

            rh1.setText(firsttunesettings.getString("rh1", ""));
```

The code doesnt throw any errors, it just doesnt seem to do anything. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need this:

```
SharedPreferences firsttunesettings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("tune1", 0);

and

SharedPreferences firsttunesettings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("tune1", 0);

            rh1.setText(firsttunesettings.getString("rh1", ""));
```

the SharedPreferences needs the context of the aplication.

the rest of the code looks good to me.

edit:
try placing your values to save first on temporary variables like this:

`String temp = firsttunesettings.getString("rh1", "");` and then:

```
rh1.setText(temp);
```

im running out off ideas since the code you posted should work fine.

edit#2:

also I declare the variables i use on shared preferences like this:

```
private static final String RH1 = "RH1";
```

and use it like this:

```
editor.putString(RH1, rh1.getText().toString());
```

and

```
String temp = firsttunesettings.getString(RH1, "");
```

this should do the trick.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick reply! It feels like its a simple problem like that but changing the code there doesnt seem to make it act any differently. Would it make any difference if the EditText and Textview are different activities?

Comment: It does seem that the Save button does something but thats only based on the "data" increasing in the app info area from 48kb to 64kb after hitting save

Comment: i have edited the answer, so did you place your context on both parts of the preferences when putting the values and when getting them right?

Comment: editor.putString("rh1", rh1.getText().toString()); how did you declare your variable "rh1"??

Comment: Thankyou. Yes i'm going to repost my new code in a new answer...hang on, EDIT In the OP

Comment: Brilliant. Thankyou! Worked great, it was saving like it was supposed to once i added the application context, trouble was it couldnt add the copied text since i hadnt set up the paste button. Thanks Again!